# PHP push reload to every user on a specific page

Tags: php

I'm currently asking myself if it's possible to send server side pushed to every user on a page triggered by one user:

[image]

I'm currently programming at my work in JSF and JEE and I know that it's possible there. So when one user is on page A and changes something there, a push is sent to all visitors on this page to do an automatic refresh for everyone. In JEE it's very complicated so I'm not sure if PHP can do something like this. Can you tell me if this is possible? It can't find anything in the web.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @Mr. Jo maybe you can research for a solution like https://pusher.com/ with JS listeners

Comment: You can use some sort of tunnel just like chats use but with content instead.

Comment: @nforced Thanks for your answer. Do you know if there is a open source library?

Comment: @Mr.Jo would use this https://petericebear.github.io/starting-laravel-echo-20170303/

Comment: @nforced I'll check it out and tell you if it works! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do something like that. For a start, I'd suggest you to use [Pusher](https://pusher.com/). If you are not using any PHP framework like Laravel, you could also take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php) to incorporate it into your code.

Basically Pusher handles the real-time logic, and all you need to do is

- Subscribe to certain events in your front-end to trigger actions, in
  this case it would be your reload
- Fire events from your PHP classes, that any subscribed clients can receive

Comment: M8, if I could I would kiss you. Works so great. Thanks a lot!